# How to write a program that function named vowel that return a nonzero C programming (HELP!!)

Tags: c

So i was trying to type this program but its keep failing , can anyone help with me ?

Write a function to return a nonzero if the character is a vowel(a, e, i, o, u – upper or lower case), or zero if it is not a vowel. Test the function in a program that allows input of string and a single character output  of the characters in the string with the vowels enclosed with angle brackets as shown.

Sample Output

Enter a name:  **Aloysius**

Result:  [A]l[o]ys[i][u]s

Note: Bold text above is the input

```
#include <stdio.h>//Question 1
#include <string.h>
 
int check_vowel();
char string[300];
int idx;
int length,status;
 
 
int main(void) {
 printf("Enter a word: ");;
 scanf("%s",string);
 length=strlen(string)-1;
 for(idx=0;idx<=length;idx++)
 {
   status=check_vowel();
   if(status==1)
     printf("<%c>",string[idx]);
   else
     printf("%c",string[idx]);
 }
 return 0;
}
 
int check_vowel()
{
length=strlen(string)-1;
for(idx=0;idx<=length;idx++)
{
switch(string[idx])
{
  case 'A': return 1; break;
  case 'a': return 1; break;
  case 'e': return 1; break;
  case 'E': return 1; break;
  case 'I': return 1; break;
  case 'i': return 1; break;
  case 'o': return 1; break;
  case 'O': return 1; break;
  case 'u': return 1; break;
  case 'U': return 1; break;
}
 }
return 0;
   
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Watch your indentation.  Badly-indented programs are difficult to read and difficult to debug.

Comment: The program question is given by my lecturer , im sry , the question is how to write a program to check whether there is vowel, if yes , make the vowel character with two angle bracket like <A> <E> <i> ..... etc . if without vowel leave it , so the display should look like this  <A> l <o> y s <i> <u> s.   The function should return a nonzero if the character is a vowel(a, e, i, o, u – upper or lower case), or zero if it is not a vowel

Comment: Your lecturer has asked you to "Write a function to return a nonzero if the *character* is a vowel". But you have written a function which checks if a *string* contains a vowel. Perhaps a good starting place for your `check_vowel` function would be to clarify the argument and return type to the function. @Fiddling Bits has shown you an example below of what that might look like.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `for` loop from `check_vowel`. Have it take a single argument, a `char`:

```
int check_vowel(char c)
{
    int is_vowel;
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            is_vowel = 1;
            break;
        default:
            is_vowel = 0;
            break;
    }
    return is_vowel;
}
```

Call `check_vowel` from `main` in a `for` loop for every `char` in `string`:

```
for(idx = 0; idx <= strlen(string); idx++)
{
    status = check_vowel(string[idx]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: but the question asked me to return a nonzero or zero

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  `check_vowel` `return`s `1` or `0`.

Comment: If we convert the character or lowercase, we can remove half the cases from the `switch`.

Answer (score -1):

how to write a program to check whether there is vowel, if yes , make the vowel character with two angle bracket like `<A> <E> <i>` ..... etc . if without vowel leave it , so the display should look like this  `<A> l <o> y s <i> <u> s`.   The function should return a nonzero if the character is a vowel(a, e, i, o, u – upper or lower case), or zero if it is not a vowel

Answer (score -1):

The function you created will check if the string contains any vowel.